# Sitecore - How to import content?

Tags: sitecore

So i got a new task to import content from a website to a new website built using Sitecore CMS. My client is doing a revamp basically. The previous website was built using a very old CMS and everything is in HTML format. I'm actually thinking to crawl the old website and dump all the contents in csv format or so...but I need to know..

1. if Sitecore provides a feature within the CMS or web service to import external data?
2. If yes, in what format (csv, xml)?
3. If not, may I know if there is any alternative or plugins?

There are so many documentations and I'm really confused where to start. I hope I don't have to write scripts to do just this.

If any of you guys have done this, itwill be great if you can share your experience.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so this is a good news / bad news situation.

Sitecore does not have a standard 'import' facility and you will very likely have to write a C# script to import your content. Sitecore allows you to define any number of data structures (templates) to shape the content types you will need for your site so a tool for importing from a CSV/XML etc is going to have a hard job as there are so many different possibilities for how the new site might be structured and the features that may be used.

The good news is that Sitecore has a very powerful C# API that makes working with data very simple and I would recommend looking at the cookbooks such as the [Content API Cookbook on SDN](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Content%20API%20Cookbook.aspx). This has information on working with templates, items and the different field types that are available.

The script you would need to write wouldnt need to be massively complicated but running a migration in a fashion such as this allows you extra room to do things like:

- Stripping HTML tags from the content. (I would suggest using HtmlAgility)
- Tracking / remapping links to old pages in the link tags.
- Removing references to images or remapping to new paths or references to the media library.
- Taking full advantage of Sitecore's different field types

I'm assuming you have not completed any Sitecore training yet and I would make this a priority so you can understand about how data and content is structured in Sitecore.

There is no silver bullet in this scenario but in my experience writing these small scripts is not time consuming and allows you to handle the often complex requirements that a content migration brings with it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There are actually two shared source migration/import tools, but I've not used them and always write my own migration for the specific site I am working on. As Stephen mentioned, there are typically too many customizations required for a general purpose import utility to work 100% of the time. http://trac.sitecore.net/DataImporter & http://trac.sitecore.net/XmlImporter

Comment: I can't believe this is going to be painful...Sitecore should provide an easier way to import or migrate data. I will try the alternatives first, hopefully that would work for my situation. Thanks guys!

Comment: Stephen Pope has hit the nail on the head here. You need custom scripts because you need to be able to structure your data properly. If you don't take the time to do that you'll pay for it ten times later, and your solution will be deprived of most of the benefits of using Sitecore in the first place. Once you've got a good data structure and mappings to the original data then the API will make this reasonably simple.

Answer (score 0):

6 years late to the party, but should anyone other than me stumple over this question, i would strongly recommend Sitecore Powershell extensions : https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx